# use system installed icons inside of visual studio code

Tags: icons, fonts, visual-studio-code

I have a weather icon pack that I installed from github:
https://github.com/erikflowers/weather-icons

when I copy/paste icon in my terminal or `gedit` for example, the icon is displayed correctly.

When I paste it in Visual Studio Code I get a empty square like this:

adding `"editor.fontFamily": "Weather Icons"` in `settings.json` didn't change anything.

How do I display icons that are installed on my system inside of vscode in Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added `Weather Icons` to the `editor.fontFamiliy` inside of `settings.json` like this:

```
"editor.fontFamily": "'Droid Sans Mono', 'monospace', monospace, 'Droid Sans Fallback', 'Weather Icons'"
```

and the weather icons appear now in my file.

I guess other `.ttf` icons could be added also. Just list them with `fc-list` and add the font name inside of `settings.json`